# Jasmine Ignoring Tests When Testing Promises

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have run into a bizarre problem. According to my log messages, the function I am testing is working correctly, but it seems to be ignoring any `expect` assertions I try to supply it.

This is the method under test:

```
getSessionContext(): Promise<ISessionContext> {
    let query = '{\
        user {\
            userId\
            clientId\
            partnerId\
            userType\
            visibleId\
            firstName\
            lastName\
            emailAddress\
            profileImageUrl\
        }\
        partner {\
            id\
            clients {\
                clientId\
                partnerId\
                clientName\
            }\
        }\
    }';

    let success = action("AuthService.getSessionContext", (sessionContext: ISessionContext) => {
        if (!sessionContext.user) {
            throw new Error('Request failed');
        }

        this.sessionContext = sessionContext;
        this.userInfo = sessionContext.user;
        this.activeClientId = this.userInfo.clientId; //default to primary client
        this.isLoggedIn = true;

        return sessionContext;
    });

    return this.graphQLService.query({query}, {unscoped: true})
        .then(success, (data) => {
            console.error('Unable to get session information', data);
        }) as Promise<ISessionContext>;
}
```

and this is my current spec:

```
fdescribe('::getSessionContext', () => {
    it('returns a valid sessionContext', () => {
        spyOn(svc.graphQLService, 'query').and.returnValue(promise_STUB);

        console.log(`sessionContext BEFORE ${JSON.stringify(svc.sessionContext)}`);
        expect(svc.sessionContext.user).toBeFalsy();
        console.log(`userInfo BEFORE ${JSON.stringify(svc.userInfo)}`);

        svc.getSessionContext().then
        (
            (result) => {
                console.log(`****************************`);
                console.log(`final result ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                console.log(`sessionContext AFTER ${JSON.stringify(svc.sessionContext)}`);
                expect(svc.sessionContext.user).toEqual({});

                console.log(`userInfo AFTER ${JSON.stringify(svc.userInfo)}`);
                expect(svc.userInfo).toEqual(promiseValue.user);

                //FIXME expect statements are being ignored
                expect(true).toBeFalsy();
                done();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This is the terminal output:

```
LOG: 'sessionContext BEFORE {"partner":{"clients":[{"clientId":1234},
{"clientId":1235},{"clientId":1236},{"clientId":1237}]}}'
LOG: 'userInfo BEFORE {"partnerId":1234,"clientId":1235}'
LOG: '****************************'
LOG: 'final result {"user":{}}'
LOG: 'sessionContext AFTER {"user":{}}'
LOG: 'userInfo AFTER {}'
```

As you can see, the terminal output confirms the function is working. However it is completely ignoring any expect statements I try to make. Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the `done` callback into the test function.

Try changing `it('returns a valid sessionContext', () => {` to be `it('returns a valid sessionContext', (done) => {`